# Thieves are they who do theft

Tags: logic

1. Thieves are they who do theft.
2. Theft is when A takes from B what belongs to B without B's consent.
3. Gov't takes from B what belongs to B without B's consent.
4. What is Gov't then?

Comment: Define consent.  If you do not consent to be taxed, you are free to leave.  If you do not leave, you have given consent.

Comment: @jobermark ahhh, I know that logic. Just watch me now. If you do not consent to be raped by me you may leave this country, but if you don't leave, you have given your consent. Tell me, do you actually get satisfied by writing psychotic rant like this?

Comment: If my parents had entered into some agreement with you to let you rape me for several generations, or had gone through some elaborate ritual to subordinate themselves to your decision as to who gets raped and who does not, that would make some sense.  But such things did not happen.  While in fact you are a hereditary or naturalizing citizen if you are being taxed.

Comment: There is nothing psychotic in asserting that tradition exists and you are bound by it.

Comment: @jobermark ahhh, but I know that logic as well. Why didn't you go straight to it? Lets see, because my parents sold me as a slave to the government, I must obey the government. Before I debunk this mornic idea, tell me, is this actually your belief and something you want to convey?

Comment: @jobermark ahhh, but I know that logic as well. Why didn't you go straight to it? Lets see, because my parents sold me as a slave to the government, I must obey the government. Before I debunk this mornic idea, tell me, is this actually your belief and something you want to convey?

Comment: (I made that an answer, apologies to those who marked the comment.)

Comment: @FrankSixteen This argument only works with a coherent theory of absolute property rights. Otherwise, there's no way to know what belongs to B. Do you have some coherent theory of absolute property rights? If not, how can we know that the government is not taking things that belong to it?

Comment: No, there is no need of absolute property rights. Even if we needed it, it would be trivial to decide who owns what just by the evidence of origin. What my argument rest upon, is solely the absence of legalized coercion. This is easily achived just by removing the weapon monopoly, preferably by force and a lot of violence. In a population it is more than enough if one man in a thousand is willing to remove the evil ones. Systematic bestial torture out in the open for everyone to watch and fear will take care of the rest. One must only be clear about the goal. Coercion is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Social contracts are negotiated. They can be wrong, but they still require something other than simple contradiction before you can expect them to go away. Forego all the benefits of a government, including the right to live safey within the borders defended by it, or address its rules with something resembling respect.

I support the Rainbow Family, who accept that they can be free of taxes as long as they accept no benefits, including safety, promised by our government. So they cannot presume the government will not violently attack them.  (And I admire them greatly for only 'attacking' back in respectful ways.)

I also support people like Priests and radical Quakers, who own nothing, and therefore are not taxed.

But I don't support pretentious Libertarians who want everything both ways.

This argument is parallel to the notion that rent is a crime.  You don't get ownership, and you are expected to pay money, so rent is theft?  No.  You get limited protection and rights for your money.  If you don't pay your rent, you are expected to leave.

(The right to ownership that is conveyed upon the lessor is itself a government function secured through taxation.  Without government action, the landlord would have to hold his property by force.  We are so used to the trappings of government-established peace that this is not obvious.  But it is proven by the existence of popular revolutions that simply reassign property rights.  So the existence of this fiction of 'ownership' does not make any difference between the two arguments.  If rent is not theft only because it is secured through government theft, then rent is theft.)

Yes, it is somehow insane that people own land or buildings at all, given that everyone must live somewhere and not everyone has access to ownership.  But it is a negotiated part of our social contract, and your parents signed on.  Some part of all social contracts will fail to make sense.  And obviously, we can change them, but only in one of two ways 1) with the leverage you can get from others subject to the same system, or 2) by imposing a different social contract wholesale from outside.

Comment: Don't write "Social contract" as if it had any meaningful content among intelligent human beings. I do expect it to go away solely because it rest upon a contradiction. I cannot help myself because the only true alternative have nothing to offer. My reasonable mind can not offer people to take part of stolen goods from legalised theft because there won't be any. All I can offer is lack of evil that comes from lack of legalized coercion of many kinds. You are right about human beings to be pretentious when calling themselves Libertarians but want from Gov't just as much as socialists. %

Comment: Why is rent and tax not contectual equals? Because somebody owns the apartment, but Gov't doesn't own the Country. You can only own what you make to put it simply. /Then forget the country, what about all the roads and stuff?/ Yes, what about that. Do you realize you're actually defend ownership of stolen goods or result thereof? Please, quit being so helplessly stupid. Think before you post. You don't want to look like like a five years old child. No you don'

Comment: Somebody owns the apartment only because the government says so.  This is proven by people's revolutions that have dissolved or rearranged ownership at will.  The owner probably did not make the apartment, so that is a non-starter.  Ownership can be established only by either contract or violence.  You are relying upon the benefits of a legal system without paying for it.  Without a social contract to fix ownership, your argument still implies rent is theft.

Comment: Oh, well if I am not intelligent enough to debate you, then I should go away.  Have a nice life being routinely ignored by everyone because you are an ass and do not listen or take other people's ideas seriously.

Comment: He doesn't realize taking him seriously is exactly what I did. Dead seriously.

Answer (score 1):

Harvard philosopher Robert Nozick (who is a staunch libertarian) addresses this issue in his book "Anarchy, State, and Utopia":

- He believes in individual freedom and that everyone has an undeniable right to ownership and to enjoying the fruits of their labor.
- Nozick notably considers that taxation and slavery are pretty much the same thing. Any type of work where you have to give 20% or 30% of your pay to the government is no different than work where you have to give up 100% pf your pay (i.e. slavery). And states that collect taxes in order to redistribute wealth for social safety nets and welfare are essentially enslaving their citizens.
- However, people *do not* have any natural rights with regards to having their rights protected by anybody else. You are totally free to keep what you rightfully own, and to enjoy all of the results of your hard work, but you are *not entitled* in anyway to being protected from any body else. If you want to insure protection of your property and resources, you will have to either do it yourself, or hire someone to do it.
- In a free market, various protection and enforcement agencies will appear to fulfill this need for protecting peoples rights. At some point these agencies will have to coordinate between themselves to define jurisdictions, rules of engagement, etc...people will naturally flock to the larger more powerful agencies if they want to maximize their chances of being protected. Sooner or later one dominant agency or group of agencies will emerge within a given geographical area.
- There will inevitably be independents, people who refuse the service of the protection agency. They are willing to assume the responsibility and consequences of defending themselves against. What happens if a conflict arises between a independent and someone who is using the protection agencies services? The agency is morally obligated to protect its client, regardless of what the independent desires. However, first it has to determine whether its client is right or whether the independent with whom the client has a conflict is right. By insuring that it can defend its clients rights, if is forced to prevent independents for defending their own rights. Its only option is therefore to defend the independents as well, whenever the need arises. But then the protection agency can legitimately charge them for this service, and is in its own rights to receive money from them for this protection. In doing so this protection agency ends taking the form a ultra-minimal government whose only job is to protect its citizens and settle disputes between them.

To summarize Nozick's position:

- taxation in general for purposes of welfare and social safety nets is in the same category as slavery and is morally wrong.
- However a government can still extract minimal compensation from its citizens in return for the service of protecting them and settling disputes between them. This government should have no duty other than the above mentioned protection of the rights of its citizens.  In this Nozick is different from anarchist libertarians who believe that there should be no government at all.

Comment: Nozick is indeed a must read for people who want to free their mind from Govt's brainwash, but not because he's a good writer, sadly, but because there are very few people who actually took the red pill. On the other hand and despite he was able to come to the only true conclusion, which is something close to a supernatural consider he rest on false premises, he has never been able to be consistent in his premises. He build it up nicely in your quotes, but finish by tearing it all down in the last paragraph. Sad. Maybe he did it deliberatly so that his readers can fill in the blanks.

Comment: I explain it and put it on the account of "too happy to be accepted within the academia": He sold his soul short. He should have come to me. I would have bought it for whatever price he wanted.

Comment: There is no right to ownership without a social contract defining its terms.  Otherwise, revolutions could not simply redistribute property a whim.  It is a very strange world where the trappings of government (rights) are assigned by some supernatural power known as Nozick.

Comment: Besides which extortion, slavery and theft are not the same thing.  This is all hopelessly muddled.  Go read a feminist.

Comment: @jobermark if one takes Nozick and libertarians on their own terms, then it is very hard to disprove them. Speaking in terms of absolute rights (and nothing else), they are correct. What drives me up the wall is just how short sighted this worldview is. A healthier, better educated population is in the interest of everybody, and those who stand to benefit the most from it are exactly those at the top. Why so many of my country men find this logic unfathomable will forever remain a mystery to me.

Comment: No, speaking in terms of absolute rights is a fiction.  We know how rights actually work in the real world.  They are enforced through extortion by those who can control you.  The question is whether you want control over those forces, or not...  People take peace for granted, and assume it is somehow automatic, because we want to believe the male role is a privilege, and not an obligation we are foisting off onto someone else.

Comment: @jobermark you are right. Maybe somebody should Quine Nozick and the libertarians, that will make them finally STFU.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing The problem is that none of them are pacifists except the truly insane fringe like the Sovereignty movements.  They never think about how much of our world would fall apart if violence were not carefully replaced with something else.  From a Nietzschean point of view, rights are chosen slavery, so if you have rights, you have slavery.  But why is that a bad choice?  (Which means I think 'The Genealogy of Morals' already Quined them, and no one wants to know that.  Hell, who reads Quine anyway...)

Comment: "Rights are chosen slavery" contains no reasonable meaning. It's nothing but psycotic rant from one that are so helplessly caught up in lies he can no longer speak in meaningful terms. There is no cure for a man if reject reason. Not because it's a deadly disease, but because it's a precise choice. Choice to be stupid and dishonest. A man who calls himself my savior when he say he must steal from me so that we both can be better educated will get nothing from it even if he was given all the education in the world. He lives by his sword like a caveman and will die without getting any wiser.

Comment: @FrankSixteen the point that jobermark is making is that claiming that freedom is the only right that deserves to be respected is totally arbitrary. If you make that claim, than you are defacto subscribing to some form of Platonic idealism where "freedom" is the new "the form of the good". Saying that freedom is the ultimate ideal, you are no better than those who base all of their decisions on Allah or Karl Marx being the ultimate source of Truth. Pragmatism is the only way to go, and pragmatism says there are better approaches than unconstrained liberty

Comment: No, it's not arbitrary, but can easily be proven. We only need an opposition. One who claims he has the right to coerce. This will instantly fail in a logical test. The burden of proof lays upon him with the action.

Comment: @FrankSixteen Cool. Can you give me the proof or link to a paper that does so? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: Maybe later. I am proving God does not exist in Philosophy right now.

Comment: If I extend you a right, someone has to enforce it.  If I agree that person can do violence to me to make me honor your right, I am effectively his slave, because he can take anything else he wants and pretend it is necessary as a way to protect your right.  Rights are chosen slavery.  This is easily proved by simply looking at how states begin to behave once someone introduces the notion of rights to them.  They eventually start assigning utterly unrelated things to the social contract and declare them necessary to protect some right or the other.

Comment: So starting from any absolute right, even one as seemingly innocuous as property, will eventually get you a military that pushes normal citizens around at will.  We need no absolute rights, but a system of balances between claims.  Anything more rigid is not safe in the long run.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing Since I don't care what Frank thinks, I guess the above explanation is a long "not exactly" answer to your summary of me.